# main thread is blocked by itself by Object.wait?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

My layout has a SurfaceView. Sometimes when my app switches from background to foreground, I get ANR. I think the reason is that the main thread is blocked by the [lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock()) method.

The most important part is :

> JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=1; globals=383 (plus 1
>   weak)
>
> DALVIK THREADS: (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
>
> "main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0
>   obj=0x4160fe58 self=0x41529b58   | sysTid=19249 nice=0 sched=0/0
>   cgrp=apps handle=1074282836   | state=S schedstat=( 140142818375
>   80057200431 501675 ) utm=11559 stm=2455 core=1   at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>     - waiting on <0x4160ff28> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main)   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)   at
>   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:813)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:846)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1175)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:180)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:256) 
>   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:524)   at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:239)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8004)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1077)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1239)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1002)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5713)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761) 
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5120)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:818)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

You see that thread(id=1) is waiting on a lock held by the thread(tid=1)! How could that be ? Do I have a wrong understanding about this?

Comment: Can you show the code where you request the lock. It'll be easier for us.
Thanks.

Comment: The method is called by Android framework, as shown in the trace file, not by my app.

Comment: Are you trying to acquire a lock anywhere in your code? If so, pls show the code.

Comment: Not from my own code. But I don't know if the 3rd party libraries do.

Comment: @uitianshi this is kind of a late reply, but were you able to find an answer to this question?

Comment: @RedaM, we didn't solve the problem. So we ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/libcore/libdvm/src/main/java/java/lang/Thread.java

```
 public void parkFor(long nanos) {
    VMThread vmt = vmThread;

    if (vmt == null) {
        // Running threads should always have an associated vmThread.
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
    synchronized (vmt) {
        switch (parkState) {
            case ParkState.PREEMPTIVELY_UNPARKED: {
                parkState = ParkState.UNPARKED;
                break;
            }
            case ParkState.UNPARKED: {
                long millis = nanos / NANOS_PER_MILLI;
                nanos %= NANOS_PER_MILLI;

                parkState = ParkState.PARKED;
                try {
                    vmt.wait(millis, (int) nanos);//<==//here  , maybe it's a normal stack.
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    interrupt();
                } finally {
                //..................
                }
```